# Detect change in lua stdin/stdout

Tags: lua, io, stdout

I have a lua script which is started by an external process - the two then interact through StandardInput and StandardOutput, through a simple loop:

```lua
local running = true;
while running do
    print('ready'); io.flush(); --the parent process now knows it can interact with the lua script
    local input = io.read(); --the parent process, whenever ready, provides the lua script with a given input
    if input=="exit" then running=false --this ends the script...
    else print(DoStuffWithInput(input)); --...or the lua script responds here
end
```

I want the lua script to end if it detects that the parent process no longer exists, given that currently CPU usage jumps to 100% when the parent is closed (presumably because `io.read()` is no longer needing to wait for any input, although I'm not sure what it's reading instead).

What would be an elegant and safe way of detecting if the parent process has closed (presumably changing the stdin and stdout of the lua script)?

I've tried a few things, but `io.stdin` and `io.stdout` always seem to be a file, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Could you provide more context? How does the parent process start the script?

Comment: You could simply store your last `input` and if it remains unchanged for a given number of loops exit.